# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages using ChromeDriver through Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]I am a newbie to selenium just trying to learn. When tried opening Chrome browser through ChromeDriver I got the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selenium_practise1_chrome.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\kulokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\kulokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\kulokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\kulokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\kulokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=a lotows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Tried alot of googling but nothing helped. Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.python.org')
print(driver.title)
```

This is not a code to deal with but I am confused what am I missing here.
Also please suggest some good online resource to learn Python Selenium. 
My chrome opened was looking like below:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Driver Error using Selenium: Unable to Discover Open Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001652/chrome-driver-error-using-selenium-unable-to-discover-open-pages)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=a lotows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *WebBrowser* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

### Solution

Add the argument **`--no-sandbox`** through `ChromeOptions()` to your existing code as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://www.python.org')
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

---

### Additional considerations

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [Version 3.14.0](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [ChromeDriver v2.41](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between *Chrome v66-68* levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.41 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Execute your *@Test*.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Nothing helped still same issue "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open window in chrome
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.79)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)"

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Works like a charm thank you. Can you suggest me best resource to learn Selenium in Python.

Comment: @k.lo Officially [Selenium Documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html) and unofficially [WebDriver API](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#) are the best documents to learn Selenium in Python.

Comment: This answer does not explain what `--no-sandbox` does nor why it fixes the issue. Obviously this answer suggest disabling a security feature that's enabled by default.  Generally this is an indication of a bad solution.  This answer needs to be improved.

Comment: This is occurring for me in electron development, is it possible that i have a wrong version of my electron and electron-chromedriver versions match, could it be affected by the version of chrome installed on my computer? i'm lost for ideas on why it is failing on this call in the vanilla built-in electron spectron implementation

Comment: @JodySowald Let's discuss in details within [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium)

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks, sorry i didn't get back to you then, I've decided to cut spectron(the thing that uses chromedrivers) out of the mix. its recommended but doesn't seem to serve a purpose aside from separating the tests from the main code, which we can organize for just fine.