# Angular-6 Protractor E2E test: Chrome crash issue

Tags: protractor, angular6

I am running e2e test in simple angular-6 application just have basic application,

[image]

though it is always giving me below error,

[image]

[image]

protractor.conf.js:

```
    // Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

    const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

    exports.config = {
      allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
      specs: [
        './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
      ],
      capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
      },
      directConnect: true,
      baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      framework: 'jasmine',
      jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        print: function() {}
      },
      onPrepare() {
        require('ts-node').register({
          project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
      }
    };
```

tsconfig.e2e.json:

```
   {
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "jasminewd2",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

angular.json:

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Angular6App": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Angular6App",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Angular6App:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Angular6App:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Angular6App:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Angular6App-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Angular6App:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "Angular6App:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Angular6App"
}
```

app.po.ts:

```
       import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

    export class AppPage {
      navigateTo() {
        return browser.get('/');
      }

      getParagraphText() {
        return element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText();
      }
    }

app.e2e-spec.ts:

    import { AppPage } from './app.po';

describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should display welcome message', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('Welcome to Angular6App!');
  });
});
```

I have tried to run app using ng serve then it is working fine. But while running test ng e2e it shows message chrome crash.

So someone knows about how to fix this issue?

Comment: What is you chrome/chromium version?

Comment: There is a [workaround solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001652/chrome-driver-error-using-selenium-unable-to-discover-open-pages) where you can diable sandbox in chrome options but this may be a chome version issue as Kacper has mentioned.

Comment: chrome version i am using...........Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)