# Selenium Chrome Webdriver not working in headless mode with profile

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, remote-debugging, google-chrome-headless

So, this is the code I'm having troubles with:

```
def scrap():
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
        options.add_argument('headless');
        options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')
        options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/omarl/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/")
        options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=45447")
    
        options.add_argument("--disable-gpu") 
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\omarl\OneDrive\Escritorio\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
        
        scrapURL = "https://es.wallapop.com/search?distance=30000&keywords=leggins&latitude=41.38804&longitude=2.17001&filters_source=quick_filters"
        browser.get(scrapURL)
        #...
```

And the error:

```
WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
```

I don't have any instances of **chrome** when I execute the script, and when I'm using it without the `headless` option it works fine. Any idea why this is happening? Please, note that I'm using the `--remote-debuggin-port` provided in similar questions.

I'm using **ChromeDriver 86.0.4240.22**

Comment: with the headless version also you are using the same executable path ?

Comment: Maybe a issue with your path. Try `options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir="C:\Users\omarl\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default"')`.

Comment: @Norhther it's hard to give you an explicit answer, because the section of code that is potentially causing you the error is omitted from your question.   Please provide additional details.

Answer (score 2):

To invoke a [Chrome Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195) in [Headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#cli) mode you can use the `--user-data-dir` argument only and you can safely remove `--profile-directory` argument as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
  # options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')
  options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Soma Bhattacharjee\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default")
  options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  print("Chrome Headless launched")
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/93c67c41-e125-4d12-abc0-fcf0f07a62f4
  Chrome Headless launched
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to open a Chrome Profile through --user-data-dir argument of Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium/50637211#50637211)
- [Selenium: Point towards default Chrome session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344560/selenium-point-towards-default-chrome-session/56401979#56401979)

---

### Additional Considerations

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [Version 3.141.0](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v86.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/86.0.4240.22/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 86.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v86.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/86.0.4240.22/notes.txt)).
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### tl; dr

[ChromeDriver remote debug port reservation race conditions](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2161)

Comment: Here you're saying `you can use...`. So the problem with my code is that I was using the args `--profile-directory` and `--user-data-dir`? Answers should be explicit about what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using arg --no-sandbox?
A lot of people on [Chrome Driver Error using Selenium: Unable to Discover Open Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001652/chrome-driver-error-using-selenium-unable-to-discover-open-pages) have had success with that argument.

Comment: This was a good idea, but something else after "browser.get" is likely causing his issue.  I'm upvoted your answer, because it was a solid attempt to help him solve his issue.